# MySQL Double count on left join

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

### Database Structure

```
CREATE TABLE installs(
    id INT, PRIMARY KEY(id), 
    created DATETIME)

CREATE TABLE uninstalls(
    id INT, PRIMARY KEY(id),
    created DATETIME,
    install_id INT)
```

### The Query ("Me vs. The MySQL")

```
SELECT DATE(installs.created),
  COUNT(installs.id),
  COUNT(uninstall.id)
FROM installs
LEFT JOIN uninstalls ON uninstalls.install_id = installs.id
GROUP BY DATE(installs.created)
```

### The "Expected" Output

```
DATE(installs.created) | COUNT(installs.id) | COUNT(uninstalls.id) 
  2012-11-20           | *installs on date* | *uninstalls on date*
```

So - I am looking a row per day, with the number of installs/uninstalls that happened on that day.

### The Problem

The data for the 'installs' is correct for each day. BUT the data for the 'uninstalls' for each day is sadly incorrect.

Comment: +1 for The structure of the question and for "Knock my head against the server"...

Comment: In what ways are the uninstall values incorrect?

Comment: The uninstalls are being grouped based on their relation to each install by the "install_id" field. So when I group by date, they are grouped into the date defined on the "install" row.

Comment: Your expected output defines the date column as coming from the install table.  Please explain the issue more clearly.  EDIT: Nevermind, I see what's going on.  Will answer with single query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count the installs and the uninstall separately, adding a column (of zeroes) for the other count to each of them.  Then combine the two with `UNION`, group by date once again and take the max for each date (to eliminate the added zeroes):

```
SELECT created as date, max(installs) as installs, max(uninstalls) as uninstalls
FROM
  (SELECT created, count(*) AS installs, 0 AS uninstalls
   FROM installs
   GROUP BY created
  UNION ALL
   SELECT created, 0 AS installs, count(*) AS uninstalls
   FROM uninstalls
   GROUP BY created) c
GROUP BY created
ORDER BY created
```

Comment: Make that `UNION ALL`. The result is the same but it will be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! This works well! I was previously doing two separate SELECT queries and then combining the results.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening because you're linking the installs and uninstalls. That is, you're showing the installs on a given date, and the uninstalls *for those installs*, not for the date of the installs.

If you want to see the count of each event on a given date, you'll need to join on the *date*, not the install ID. If it's a large data set, it's going to be very slow (the optimizer can't use indexes on a field when you group by or join based on a function on that field).

```
SELECT DATE(installs.created),
  COUNT(installs.id),
  COUNT(uninstall.id)
FROM installs 
LEFT JOIN uninstalls ON DATE(uninstalls.created) = DATE(installs.created)
GROUP BY DATE(installs.created)
```

Comment: should be full outer join, in case an uninstall is done on a date when no installs were done.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support full outer joins, sadly.

Comment: A full outer join would be a problem for the group by also.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. If there are no installs matching any uninstalls on that date (or vice versa) it counts "null" rows and thus outputs the same false data for for each day in the "installs" and "uninstalls" column.

Comment: You need to show only uninstalls that happened on the same date as their associated install? or _all_ uninstalls that happened on the date? My answer doesn't cover the former situation.

Comment: As your relation is based on the 'created' field, if there are no installs on a day when 10 uninstalls happened, those 10 uninstalls won't appear in the final listing as there was no relation to them in the installs table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CTE that includes all dates for installs and uninstalls, then join to install and uninstall table separately.

```
; WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT DATE(created) AS created
    FROM
    (
        SELECT created
        FROM installs

            UNION ALL

        SELECT created
        FROM uninstalls
    ) a
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
)
, InstallCTE AS
(
    SELECT DATE(created) AS created
        , COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM installs
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
)
, UninstallCTE AS
(
    SELECT DATE(created) AS created
        , COUNT(*) AS c
    FROM uninstalls
    GROUP BY DATE(created)
)
SELECT d.created AS [date]
    , i.c AS install_count
    , u.c AS uninstall_count
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN InstallCTE i
    ON d.created = i.created
LEFT JOIN UninstallCTE u
    ON d.created = u.created
```